# What does `<&-` do?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I copied a snippet of Bash to background an ssh command executed remotely:

```
ssh user@remote <<CMD
some process <&- >log 2>error &
CMD
```

What does `<&-` do?
My guess is that it is the same as `< /dev/null`

My next understanding is that the three main file descriptors (`stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`) need to be closed to prevent:

1. The job being backgrounded and the script exiting -- conflicting
   somehow?
2. When the terminal closes, all processes that are
   accepting stdin from terminal are closed?

Comment: Obligatory cross-reference: See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216) — although all it says about this operator is that it "can be used to close or duplicate file descriptors" and you should "see the relevant section of your shell's manual".

Comment: If I recall correctly, `ssh -nNT user@remote 'command'` will create a non-interactive SSH session.  Append `&` to background it, prepend `nohup` to the `command` to keep it running if your connection dies.

Comment: @MarkKCowan `man ssh` suggests that -N disables running a remote command entirely, and a quick test supports that.

Comment: Ah yes, I used -nNTR for reverse port forwarding.  Ignore the -N and -R then :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`<&-` is not *quite* the same thing as `< /dev/null`. `<&-` closes fd 0, whereas `< /dev/null` redirects it from the device `/dev/null`, which never provides any data and always gives EOF on read. The difference is mostly that a `read(2)` call from a closed FD (the `<&-` case) will error with EBADF, whereas a call from a null-redirected FD will return no bytes read (end-of-file condition). If your program never reads from stdin, the distinction doesn't matter.

Closing the FDs is good practice if you're backgrounding something, since a backgrounded process will hang if it tries to read anything from TTY. This example doesn't fully handle everything it should, though; ideally there would be a `nohup` or `setsid` invocation somewhere, to fully disassociate the background process.

Comment: So I should use `nohup` in addition to closing file descriptors?

Comment: The most thorough method (which imitates the way programs daemonize themselves) is something like `setsid some process <&- >path/to/log 2>path/to/error`. The quicker method is something like `nohup some process &`.

Comment: @EricFrancis: Using `nohup` make no sense here. `nohup` prevent process from receiving `HUP` signal when its control terminal closed. But you didn't have any terminal in this case.

Comment: @TomHunt: The background process didn't hang, the ssh session did.

Comment: not a good idea to close fds 0, 1 & 2 ... you don't want the next fd created to take up one of those values. better to redirect them to /dev/null

Comment: @MurrayJensen True enough. Presumably if you're closing them you're stating intent to stop using functions that default to them, but no point in tempting fate.

Comment: @MurrayJensen I don't understand. Can you refer me to a resource that explains "you don't want the next fd created to take up one of those values"?  Also, which comment were you responding to?

Comment: when you open a file the system creates a file descriptor and assigns it the smallest non-negative number that is not already assigned. e.g. if you close file descriptor 0, the next successful open will return 0. the convention is for file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 to have special meaning, being stdin, stdout and stderr resp.  so closing fds 0, 1 or 2 instead of redirecting from/to /dev/null could mean you have an ordinary fd being used as a standard input or output channel. I was commenting on the main response "Closing the FDs is good practice ..." - which is true, except for fds 0, 1 & 2.

Answer (score 7):

See `man bash`:

> ```
>   [n]<&word
> ```
>
> is  used  to duplicate input file descriptors.  If `word` expands to one or more digits,
>          the file descriptor denoted by `n` is made to be a copy of that file descriptor.  If the
>          digits  in  `word`  do not specify a file descriptor open for input, a redirection error
>          occurs.  If word evaluates to `-`, file descriptor `n` is closed.  If `n` is not  specified,
>          the standard input (file descriptor 0) is used.

Comment: The correct definition is that it is unspecified what happens when you have `[n]<&word` and word contains more than a single digit.

Comment: What do you mean? Is the `man bash` incorrect?

Comment: @EricFrancis because it is unspecified in the standard, `bash` chooses to implement it in a sane way (for some suitable definition of "sane"). Other shells may or may not do so.

Comment: @muru The question is tagged `bash`, not `posix-shell`.

Comment: @Barmar ok. So...?

Answer (score 7):

`<&-` close standard input.

The [general form, defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_05), is:

```
[n]<&word
```

Its purpose to made file descriptor `n` is a copy of file descriptor denoted by `word`. Standard in is assumed if `n` is omitted, and if `word` is `-`, the file descriptor `n` will be closed.

It's not the same as `</dev/null`, since when in case of `</dev/null`, the standard input still opened, and was redirected to other place.

You need to closed all file descriptors of processes which were attached to ssh socket, otherwise, ssh session can not close.

You can run the command on remote machine without attach it to ssh session, by using [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/):

```
ssh user@remote 'screen -S test -d -m command'
```

Comment: Why the down vote?